# C# MD5 hashing needs to match PHP MD5 hashing (with salt)

Tags: c#, php, hash, salt

I have a string that needs to be hashed using a salt in C# and match what it would in PHP. The C# code is as follows:

```
        string stringToHash = "123";
        string saltToUse = "321";
        byte[] stringBytes = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(stringToHash);
        byte[] saltBytes = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(saltToUse);

        var hmacMD5 = new HMACMD5(saltBytes);
        var saltedHash = hmacMD5.ComputeHash(stringBytes);
        byte[] hashedBytesNoSalt = MD5CryptoServiceProvider.Create().ComputeHash(stringBytes);

        string hashedString = BitConverter.ToString(hashedBytesNoSalt).Replace("-", "").ToLower();
        string saltedString = BitConverter.ToString(saltedHash).Replace("-", "").ToLower();
```

The PHP code to test if the C# is outputting correctly is:

```
<?php echo md5('123'.'321'); ?>
```

The C# outputs the correct UNSALTED MD5 hash, which is 202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70. However, when I try to salt using C# I get 900011ae860f471561023fba6cc25df6 and with PHP I get c8837b23ff8aaa8a2dde915473ce0991.

I am not sure why it is doing this or if this is even the correct way. The thing to remember is the C# needs to output to what the PHP outputs to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A salt is not the same thing as a private key. `HMACMD5` uses a private key, when all that you desire is a salted MD5 hash. Just append the salt to the string to generate the correct key... `stringToHash + saltToUse`.

Read about `HMACMD5` here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd9e7dt2.aspx

Comment: byte[] stringBytes = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(stringToHash + saltToUse);

Did that and it works perfectly, thank you!

Comment: Can you explain how it does not work? Perhaps open a new question?

Comment: Will do. Thanks again, I'll re-edit that out and remark this right as per the original hash + salt.

Answer (score 2):

The C# code is using a better salting mechanism than the PHP code. To match the PHP, all you need to do is run MD5 on `stringToHash + saltToUse` instead of using the HMACMD5's key feature. In short, do exactly what you did to produce your unsalted MD5 in C#, but pass in `stringToHash + saltToUse` instead.

Comment: Yes, your idea was right, too. Thanks for the speedy responses.